# set covering in shipments between cities

Tags: algorithm, optimization

There is a number of warehouses in different cities in which different products are kept. Each warehouse may keep a number of units of a product e.g (warehouse in Chicago keeps 14 units of A product, 20 units of B product, 0 units of C etc.). There is a list of orders also (consisting of destination city and amount of products needed). What I need to obtain is minimum number of shipments while fulfilling all the orders (minimum number of unique pairs between cities).  Distance between these cities is not important.

To clarify: sample input looks like this:

```
WAREHOUSES

LOCATION | PRODUCT | AMOUNT
---------+---------+-------
Chicago  |   p1    |   14 
Chicago  |   p2    |    3
New York |   p1    |    2  
New York |   p3    |    7
Dallas   |   p2    |    3


ORDERS

DESTINATION | PRODUCT | AMOUNT
------------+---------+-------
Houston     |   p1    |   12 
Phoenix     |   p1    |    4
Houston     |   p3    |    2  
Detroit     |   p2    |    3
Phoenix     |   p2    |    2
```

and the output:

```
LOCATION | DESTINATION | PRODUCT | AMOUNT
---------+-------------+---------+-------
Chicago  | Houston     |    p1   |   12
Chicago  | Phoenix     |    p1   |    2
New York | Phoenix     |    p1   |    2
Chicago  | Phoenix     |    p2   |    2
Dallas   | Detroit     |    p2   |    3
New York | Houston     |    p3   |    2

and number of unique pairs is: 5
```

The problem is very similar to the one found here: [Algorithm to Minimize Number of Shipments from Multiple Warehouses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976664/algorithm-to-minimize-number-of-shipments-from-multiple-warehouses), however, it does not take into account possibility of ordering several units of particular product and the fact, that there is more than one order.

For me it looks like a mix of two kinds of problem: set covering and transportation problem. Is there any approach to solve this task without use of greedy algorithm? Or maybe I'm just missing something and it's solvable with simple set-covering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an exact solution, the standard approach would be to model it as an Integer Program (IP) and then use an IP solver (e.g. [CBC](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc), [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/), etc.). If you're satisfied with a heuristic solution, [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) is easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a bipartite graph from your problem and transform it to a maximum flow with multiple source. Then there are some algorithm with polynominal time constant? Read here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full solution off the top of my head, but you can simplify it by considering each product separately.

That's unless you misstated the question and meant to say that an order is allowed to include two different products.